# Mailchimp Campaign Send Error - This Campaign has already been sent and can not be sent again

Tags: c#, asp.net, mailchimp, perceptivemcapi

I have a Mailchimp RSS campaign that reads an RSS feed on a website and is set to once a day. I would like to send this campaign pro-grammatically after I add an item to the feed.

I am using PerceptiveMCAPI and My code for triggering the campaign is

```
campaignSendNowInput campaignSendNowInput = new campaignSendNowInput(apiKey, campaignKey);
campaignSendNow campaignSendNow = new campaignSendNow(campaignSendNowInput);
campaignSendNowOutput campaignSendNowOutput = campaignSendNow.Execute();
```

The error I receive looks like

```
"Error Code: 313, Message: This Campaign has already been sent and can not be sent again."
```

Any ideas on what would be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think after looking this over a bit more I originally had the wrong logic. The correct way I believe is to create a new campaign each time and then send this new campaign. Campaigns are meant to be sent once.

RSS feed announcements in Mailchimp are limited to once a day therefor you need to use a standard campaign which you can create pro-grammatically and send that campaign off. If it is vital that the content come from an RSS feed you can still use an RSS feed using the RSS merge tags.